# I have a problem: React styled-components &(parent selector)

Tags: css, reactjs, sass, css-selectors, styled-components

**Goal**: I want to give flex style to the child components(Header, Login, Footer) of the Container.

Given the following code(started with create-react-app --typescript):

#### src/App.tsx

```
import React from 'react';
import logo from './logo.svg';
import styled from 'styled-components';
import Footer from './component/Footer/Footer';
import Login from './component/Login/Login';
import Header from './component/Header/Header';

function App() {
  return (
    <>
      <Container>
        <Header />
        <Login />
        <Footer />
      </Container>
    </>
  );
}

const Container = styled.div`
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  height: 100vh;
  background-color: #7f8c8d;

  &:nth-child(1) {
    flex: 1 1 15%;
  }
  &:nth-child(2) {
    flex: 1 1 75%;
  }
  &:nth-child(3) {
    flex: 1 1 5%;
  }
`;

export default App;
```

#### src/component/Footer/Footer.tsx

```
import React from 'react';
import { FC } from 'react';
import styled from 'styled-components';

interface FooterProps {}

const Footer: FC<FooterProps> = () => {
  return <Container>Footer</Container>;
};

const Container = styled.footer`
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  background-color: #2980b9;
`;
export default Footer;
```

#### src/component/Header/Header.tsx

```
import React from 'react';
import { FC } from 'react';
import styled from 'styled-components';

interface HeaderProps {}

const Header: FC<HeaderProps> = () => {
  return <Container>Header</Container>;
};

const Container = styled.header`
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  background-color: #2980b9;
`;

export default Header;
```

#### src/component/Login/Login.tsx

```
import React from 'react';
import { FC } from 'react';
import styled from 'styled-components';

interface LoginProps {}

const Login: FC<LoginProps> = () => {
  return <Container>Login</Container>;
};

const Container = styled.main`
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  background-color: #ecf0f1;
`;

export default Login;
```

##### App rendering result

[image]

the problem part is Container at App.tsx (styled.div)

```
const Container = styled.div`
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  height: 100vh;
  background-color: #7f8c8d;

  &:nth-child(1) {
    flex: 1 1 15%;
  }
  &:nth-child(2) {
    flex: 1 1 75%;
  }
  &:nth-child(3) {
    flex: 1 1 5%;
  }
`;
```

I tried several codes like: (it works)

```
const Container = styled.div`
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  height: 100vh;
  background-color: #7f8c8d;

  & :nth-child(1) {
    flex: 1 1 15%;
  }
  & :nth-child(2) {
    flex: 1 1 75%;
  }
  & :nth-child(3) {
    flex: 1 1 5%;
  }
`;
```

and

```
const Container = styled.div`
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  height: 100vh;
  background-color: #7f8c8d;

  & > :nth-child(1) {
    flex: 1 1 15%;
  }
  & > :nth-child(2) {
    flex: 1 1 75%;
  }
  & > :nth-child(3) {
    flex: 1 1 5%;
  }
`;
```

##### code result

[image]

The code I tried to change worked well, but I don't understand why it works like this.

Why isn't this working?

```
  &:nth-child(1) {
    flex: 1 1 15%;
  }
  &:nth-child(2) {
    flex: 1 1 75%;
  }
  &:nth-child(3) {
    flex: 1 1 5%;
  }
```

Comment: What's the transpiled CSS, or what shows up in devtools?

Comment: `&:nth-child (1)` is applied to the `Container` component.

Comment: Well the browser cannot understand that, that is Sass code which needs to be transpiled to CSS